# Who defines the Bootloader Specification

Tags: architecture, operating-system, x86, x86-64, bootloader

I know bootloader needs to be exactly 512KB is size, 511 & 512 Byte need to be AA55 and it need to be located in the first sector of the disk. This AA55 is the boot signature. Who defines that it should be AA55 and not suppose BB23

The thing I need to know is who defines these specification. Most probably it in is the motherboard spec sheet or may be in the processor spec sheet. Where are these defined.

I need to reach to the heart of it to start making some production level apps.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably tag `x86` since this is most likely specific to that architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the BIOS specification.

Originally BIOS what just the way IBM implemented their firmware. When competitors wanted to make hardware that was compatible with DOS or IBM PCs, they had to reverse engineer IBM's BIOS in order to do this. So basically somebody at IBM did that years ago and it became standard once it was reverse engineered and copied.

Comment: thanks for the insight. I did not know the reverse engineering part but I found rest of it. Including some docs http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals